# SQL command to update posts in Wordpress database

Tags: sql, wordpress

Some users have been adding links on my website that are monetized.
They take the form of:

"href="http://redirect.viglink.com/?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsports.ca.msn.com"

I want to a search/replace on all posts (approximately 200,000), so that any links that are like the above, remove the "http://redirect.viglink.com/?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&u=http%3A%2F%2F" part of the link, leaving just the "http://sports.ca.msn.com"

Would the following sql do the trick:

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'http://redirect.viglink.com/?key=11fe087258b6fc0532a5ccfc924805c0&u=http%3A%2F%2F','http://')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it right.

But I also think that you may want to add this `WHERE post_content LIKE %redirect.viglink.com%` to the end of the SQL statement.

the WHERE simply makes it faster, but is not necessary.